# How can I make a free form image, the background of my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on the navigation bar of my website. The background image of the navigation bar is a 2" paper that's been ripped towards the bottom of the page, leaving the rest of the background image transparent. Since it's not a filled square or rectangle, it needs to overlap the contents below it, which I am struggling with. Thank you! Much Appreciated! My profile pic is literally how I feel right now.

Image of what i'm trying to achieve:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LHXn.png)

HTML

```
  <nav>
    <div class="topnav">
      <div id="logo-img">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/xsfiller.png" alt="Forever in the Stars Logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="menu-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="active" href="#">Our Vision</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Digital Marketing Service</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{
}
.topnav{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;

  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;

  justify-content: center;

  background-image: url('img/main/nav-bar-bckgrnd.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 100;
}
nav ul{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*The rest of the code is formatting the text and logo...*/
```

Image of my code's result:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvN1A.png)

Answer (score 0):

How does the correct version work responsively? You will need to either have it repeat on the x axis or have a wide enough image to never see the end. I think the best way is to get a recurring image where the left matches up the right, set the nav height to whatever you need to fit the entire image, set the background to 100% height and auto width.
Then the div content underneath can be brought up with a negative margin.
Hope that explains it well enough.